# where to unzip the pytesser.zip file

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-12.04, tesseract

I am new to python and i am using pytesser for an project i have downloaded the file pytesser_v0.0.1.zip and i have also installed tesseract-ocr. My doubt is where to unzip the files inside the pytesser_v0.0.1.zip(To which folder should I copy this unziped files). I mean I want that pytesser should work with all my projects on the disk by using the command

```
from pytesser import *
```

inside the project.
I tried it in windows and it is working fine.

But I do not know where to copy the files in ubuntu.
I am using ubuntu 12.04

Hope you understood my problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First run python console and write

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

This is a correct place when u can put your new module